# Ubuntu 14.04 Ibus QWERTZ QWERTY problem

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout, ibus

I use Anthy to input Japanese and Ibus Pinyin to input Chinese on Ubuntu 14.04.
However Ibus won't respect that I'm using a German keyboard and forces an US layout when I'm using Anthy and Pinyin, so that Z and Y are exchanged, which always throws me off when typing.
Now I'm wondering how to make Ibus use German keyboard layout for Anthy and Pinyin.
I've already checked the "use system keyboard layout" in the ibus-setup menu but that didn't help.

Comment: Check this bug release https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1302353 which is similar to what you are experiencing and check if it helps.

Comment: Well, it fixes the layout of Anthy, however with the Pinyin engine the wrong layout persists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the "Intelligent Pinyin" from the `ibus-libpinyin` package that respects the german keyboard.

[Make sure to uninstall ibus-pinyin](http://www.pinyinjoe.com/faq/ubuntu-1404-chinese-ime-problems-faq.htm).

```
apt-get remove ibus-pinyin
apt-get install ibus-libpinyin
```